# Problem with multiple uploading image

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I use codeigniter. I want multiple upload image, for this work, i use `library Multi_upload` and `jquery.MultiFile`.

i have in output, this `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) no` => this is is from line 18 (`print_r($error);echo 'no';`) in the my code, and inserted to databse table this: `[]`(i want insert file name) . how can fix it?

My Html: `http://pastebin.com/8YWJS2hy`

library Multi_upload: `http://pastebin.com/115ASstV`

jquery.MultiFile: `http://pastebin.com/0cyU8HvA`

**My Controller:**

```
function insert_data(){
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; // server directory
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '512';

    $this->load->library('Multi_upload');
    $error = array();
    $data  = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++) {
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->multi_upload->go_upload('userfile', $i)) {
            $error[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        $data[$i] = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
        //gradually build up upload->data()
    }

    if (count($error) > 0) {
        print_r($error); //Line 18
        echo 'no';
    } else {
        print_r($data);
        echo 'ok';
    }

    $data = array(
        //'name' => $this -> input -> post('name'),
        //'term' => $this -> input -> post('term'),
        'image' => json_encode($data)
    );

    $this->db->insert('table', $data);
}
```

Comment: Please attach the HTML file. I'm almost 100% sure the problem is there and not in the PHP code (if you fixed the issue below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count $_FILES['userfile'] , not the name inside.

Also make sure that at the HTML page sending the request , all file fields are called userfile[] (e.g. )

Comment: I change it, and get this error: `Message: Undefined index: userfile`. in html all is set

Comment: @Emmy this means you're not sending the correct data from the HTML file. Could you edit your original post and show the HTML file with the form as well?

Comment: I changed `count($_FILES['userfile']['name'])` to `count($_FILES['userfile']['userfile'])` and get it error. this is my html: `<input type="file" class="multi" name="userfile[]" valign="baseline" value="">`, i update the post and put class Multi_upload , Please see it.

Comment: It should be count($_FILES['userfile']);

Comment: I changed but there is still a problem, I think that problem is from class `Multi_upload` in my post!?

Comment: I don't think so, because the count returns 0, meaning something in your HTML file or PHP is wrong. I would suggest pasting your entire HTML to a site like pastebin.com and putting the link here so i can try helping.

Comment: I'm only seeing one file there - not multiple files.

Comment: http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/admin/tour_foreign/insert_data are you sure this is the link to the php file? Also it seems you are only sending a single file and not an array of files... for some reason. Please read thoroughly this tutorial. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: this link is same **My Controller:** in the my post. did you see it?

Comment: As i said, i believe there is some problem with your knowledge for Multiple Uploads and i think reading the link i attached first would be a good idea. I don't think i have anything else to add. Make sure you actually send the HTML to the correct PHP file because it doesn't seem so.

Comment: you see that html file don't have problem, I say, is probably a problem of PHP

Comment: I'm not using code ignitor so i can't really test your code, unfortunately.